# How to query from Google Datastore using NOT LIKE filter condition?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I use as `NOT LIKE` SQL operator in Python and Google App Engine data store? I want to filter string in database.

```
q = Post.all()
q.filter("text NOT LIKE", "%Something%")
```

Comment: It would be better if you added some examples of what exactly you want the output of query to be

Comment: Also read up on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Really your question is not so correct but you can see here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported by AppEngine Datastore.

The datastore can query entities just by indexes (*and get by ID and SELECT without any filters/order are basically queries over index on key*).

This is an architectural limitation of the distributed data storage.

There are solution which can do what you want but Google Cloud Datastore is not one of them.

Comment: I want to filter string out put example in sql: %some% How can I do it on google cloud datastore?

Comment: You can load more entities and filter out in python code but this can be costly. If your set of filters is limited and known in advance you can add a list of strings property and add flags to entities signaling if the entity satisfy your condition. Then you filter by that list property using =.

Comment: If you really need arbitary NOT LIKE or LIKE search you better of with Cloud SQL or any other SQL solution or maybe hadoop or something similar. There are a lot of options and the choice is really depends on your needs & skills.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try now #Alexander Trakhimenok